# Parse nested JSON from the Foursquare API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, foursquare

I'm attempting to parse a JSON response from Foursquare. It's nested in a way that I cannot figure out. [Here's a copy of the entire JSON](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7jyrjrknp00y0r/category.json?dl=0).

Here's a snippet of of the JSON:

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "requestId": "58cab8bc4434b959e2f68a69"
},
"response": {
    "categories": [
        {
            "categories": [
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734db",
                    "name": "Amphitheater",
                    "pluralName": "Amphitheaters",
                    "shortName": "Amphitheater"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/aquarium_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823",
                    "name": "Aquarium",
                    "pluralName": "Aquariums",
                    "shortName": "Aquarium"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/arcade_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735",
                    "name": "Arcade",
                    "pluralName": "Arcades",
                    "shortName": "Arcade"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/artgallery_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e2931735",
                    "name": "Art Gallery",
                    "pluralName": "Art Galleries",
                    "shortName": "Art Gallery"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/bowling_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e4931735",
                    "name": "Bowling Alley",
                    "pluralName": "Bowling Alleys",
                    "shortName": "Bowling Alley"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/casino_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d17c941735",
                    "name": "Casino",
                    "pluralName": "Casinos",
                    "shortName": "Casino"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79e7",
                    "name": "Circus",
                    "pluralName": "Circuses",
                    "shortName": "Circus"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/comedyclub_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d18e941735",
                    "name": "Comedy Club",
                    "pluralName": "Comedy Clubs",
                    "shortName": "Comedy Club"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/musicvenue_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c",
                    "name": "Concert Hall",
                    "pluralName": "Concert Halls",
                    "shortName": "Concert Hall"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/performingarts_dancestudio_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79ef",
                    "name": "Country Dance Club",
                    "pluralName": "Country Dance Clubs",
                    "shortName": "Country Dance Club"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79e8",
                    "name": "Disc Golf",
                    "pluralName": "Disc Golf Courses",
                    "shortName": "Disc Golf"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "56aa371be4b08b9a8d573532",
                    "name": "Exhibit",
                    "pluralName": "Exhibits",
                    "shortName": "Exhibit"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1f1931735",
                    "name": "General Entertainment",
                    "pluralName": "General Entertainment",
                    "shortName": "Entertainment"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/racetrack_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79ea",
                    "name": "Go Kart Track",
                    "pluralName": "Go Kart Tracks",
                    "shortName": "Go Kart"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/historicsite_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4deefb944765f83613cdba6e",
                    "name": "Historic Site",
                    "pluralName": "Historic Sites",
                    "shortName": "Historic Site"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/nightlife/karaoke_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "5744ccdfe4b0c0459246b4bb",
                    "name": "Karaoke Box",
                    "pluralName": "Karaoke Boxes",
                    "shortName": "Karaoke"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79e6",
                    "name": "Laser Tag",
                    "pluralName": "Laser Tag Places",
                    "shortName": "Laser Tag"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/historicsite_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "5642206c498e4bfca532186c",
                    "name": "Memorial Site",
                    "pluralName": "Memorial Sites",
                    "shortName": "Memorial Site"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/golfcourse_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79eb",
                    "name": "Mini Golf",
                    "pluralName": "Mini Golf Courses",
                    "shortName": "Mini Golf"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734de",
                            "name": "Drive-in Theater",
                            "pluralName": "Drive-in Theaters",
                            "shortName": "Drive-in Theater"
                        },
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d17e941735",
                            "name": "Indie Movie Theater",
                            "pluralName": "Indie Movie Theaters",
                            "shortName": "Indie Movies"
                        },
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d180941735",
                            "name": "Multiplex",
                            "pluralName": "Multiplexes",
                            "shortName": "Cineplex"
                        }
                    ],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735",
                    "name": "Movie Theater",
                    "pluralName": "Movie Theaters",
                    "shortName": "Movie Theater"
                },
                {
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/museum_art_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d18f941735",
                            "name": "Art Museum",
                            "pluralName": "Art Museums",
                            "shortName": "Art Museum"
                        },
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/nightlife/stripclub_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "559acbe0498e472f1a53fa23",
                            "name": "Erotic Museum",
                            "pluralName": "Erotic Museums",
                            "shortName": "Erotic Museum"
                        },
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/museum_history_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d190941735",
                            "name": "History Museum",
                            "pluralName": "History Museums",
                            "shortName": "History Museum"
                        },
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/museum_planetarium_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d192941735",
                            "name": "Planetarium",
                            "pluralName": "Planetariums",
                            "shortName": "Planetarium"
                        },
                        {
                            "categories": [],
                            "icon": {
                                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/museum_science_",
                                "suffix": ".png"
                            },
                            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d191941735",
                            "name": "Science Museum",
                            "pluralName": "Science Museums",
                            "shortName": "Science Museum"
                        }
                    ],
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/museum_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d181941735",
                    "name": "Museum",
                    "pluralName": "Museums",
                    "shortName": "Museum"
                },
            "icon": {
                "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
                "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "id": "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259",
            "name": "Arts & Entertainment",
            "pluralName": "Arts & Entertainment",
            "shortName": "Arts & Entertainment"
        },
```

My code pulls the first hierarchy, which is always listed below it's sub-categories.

```
import urllib.request
import json 
import sqlite3
from key import ID, SECRET

CLIENT_ID = ID
CLIENT_SECRET = SECRET
v = '20170315'

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id='+ CLIENT_ID +'&client_secret=' + SECRET + '&v=' + v

contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

parsed = json.loads(contents)


clean = parsed['response']['categories']
my_list = [i['name'] for i in clean]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['Arts & Entertainment', 'College & University', 'Event', 'Food', 'Nightlife Spot', 'Outdoors & Recreation', 'Professional & Other Places', 'Residence', 'Shop & Service', 'Travel & Transport']
```

I'm having trouble parsing to get the sub-categories. I'm trying to pull `id` and `name` for all categories, sub or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a data structure is recursively nested, a recursive function is often the easiest way to parse it:

```
def get_categories(data):
    result = {}
    for cat in data:
        result[cat['id']] = cat['name']
        if cat['categories']:
            result.update(get_categories(cat['categories']))
    return result
```

This returns a dictionary of `id: name` key/value pairs, recursively calling itself and updating `result` with any subcategories it finds along the way.

The `if` check is not strictly necessary, since calling the function with an empty list would simply return an empty dictionary, but it saves a lot of pointless recursive calls, so ought to improve performance.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
categories = get_categories(parsed['response']['categories'])
```

… and here's the result:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(categories)
{'4bf58dd8d48988d100941735': 'Meeting Room',
 '4bf58dd8d48988d100951735': 'Pet Store',
 '4bf58dd8d48988d101941735': 'Martial Arts Dojo',
   # ...
 '57558b36e4b065ecebd306da': 'Savoyard Restaurant',
 '57558b36e4b065ecebd306dd': 'Truck Stop',
 '589ddde98ae3635c072819ee': 'Duty-free Shop'}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm and I'm going to look up more about recursive functions.